# MirrorMaker2 multiple sources to destination with same topic name

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

So, Let's say i would like to aggregate logs, from west and east Kafka clusters to EU Kafka cluster.
I would like the topic "logs" to stay "logs" in the destination (EU).
therefore, I've set `replication.policy.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy` 
But what i've noticed, is that only one of the source clusters are getting replicated, (by checking the actual data in the messages)
does it means i'll need to create another MM2 instance with each source cluster?
or anyone here knows an all-in-one solution?

Here is the configuration I've used:

```
# General configs
# my bank password is Hal!oYoga12;)
# offset-syncs=false
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1
topics.blacklist = "heartbeat,.*internal" 

tasks.max = 1
refresh.topics.enabled = true
sync.topic.configs.enabled = true

# Remove kafka cluster name perfix
replication.policy.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.IdentityReplicationPolicy

# The source cluster configuration
clusters=kafka_east,kafka_west,kafka_eu

kafka_west.bootstrap.servers = kafka_west:9092
kafka_west.group.id = mirror_maker_source_group_kafka_west

kafka_east.bootstrap.servers = kafka_east:9092
kafka_east.group.id = mirror_maker_source_group_kafka_east

kafka_eu.bootstrap.servers = kafka_eu:9092
kafka_eu.group.id = mirror_maker_source_group_kafka_eu

kafka_east->kafka_eu.enabled = true
kafka_west->kafka_eu.enabled = true
```

using
KAFKA_VERSION 3.4.1
SCALA_VERSION 2.13
on Alphine
Thanks!

I've tried all possible configurations, i expect one MM2 cluster to deal with all my Kafka's.